# No output using vagrant Windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm not sure if this belongs her or another site, so let me know and I'll remove it if not. So I'm attempting to install vagrant on a windows 10 machine. I have virtual box installed, I have a kali linux machine on it that I've used in the past. After using the msi to install vagrant, I rebooted as prompted. After reboot I verified vagrant was added to the path.

Issuing any vagrant command shows nothing in the output. I've tried passing `-h` and `--version` and nothing shows. Even running as admin and powershell gives no response. No hanging or freezing, just nothing in the response. Not even a command not recognized warning(more validation its in my path).

Can anyone help me find out whats going on and why none of the vagrant commands seem to respond?

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
C:\>vagrant init -h

C:\>vagrant --version

C:\>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

im guessing its something to do with their latest 1.9.7 version? i installed 1.9.6 and it finally gives me some output.

Comment: Got the same issue today. Clean install of Virtual Box and Vagrant 1.9.7 64 bit on a Windows 10 64 bit. No output from Vagrant. Installed 1.9.6 and everything works know. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Blowingfish sure thing! dont want to leave any loose ends. Sounds like almost my same setup. Glad I saved you some troubles

Comment: Is there a bug filed for this?

Comment: @SamMartin I did not file one. If someone else did, I do not know.

Comment: a simple google search showed me it is reported, a couple of times actually.
[1.9.7 no output whatsoever under cygwin/babun](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8764)